# javascript FileReader - how to parsing long file in chunks?

Tags: javascript

Initially, I have made loading here so [like this](http://jsbin.com/sonibalego/edit?js)

```
export function сonvertFilesToByteArray(e) {
  const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 50; // 50MB
  const files = Object.keys(e.target.files);
  const asyncReadFile = eachFile =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (e.target.files[eachFile].size > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        return reject([{ message: `File ${e.target.files[eachFile].name} too large` }]);
      }
      const reader = new FileReader();
      const targetFileInfo = {
        contentType: e.target.files[eachFile].type,
        filename: e.target.files[eachFile].name,
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[eachFile]);
      reader.onload = () => {
        resolve({ ...targetFileInfo, body: Array.from(new Uint8Array(reader.result)) });
      };
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });

  return Promise.all(files.map(asyncReadFile));
}
```

Here in the constant files, I define how many at my files and I apply a function to each of them.

And then I get my file(s) in the component

```
handleFileUpload = (e) => {
    сonvertFilesToByteArray(e)
      .then((result) => {
        runInAction(() => {
          this.files = [
            ...this.files,
            ...result,
          ];
        });
      })
      .catch(err => runInAction(() => {
        this.errors = [...this.errors, err[0].message];
      }));
  }
```

And put in `this.files` and finally my `this.files` looks like `[{contentType: 'plain/text', filename: 'blabla', body: [123, 456, 23, ...] }]`

Where [123, 456, 23...] there is my ArrayBuffer

But at such approach in spite of the fact that I use Promise.all, when loading files/files which have weight more ~ 2MB, the page is frozen, it is impossible to interact with her in any way (but I can scroll). Except as realization when each file are divided into chunks nothing has come to mind to correct a situation. 
Ok, I try to rewrite the code: [With chunks](http://jsbin.com/vexekojemi/edit?js)

```
export function сonvertFilesToByteArray(e) {
  const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 50; // 50MB
  const files = Object.keys(e.target.files);
  const asyncReadFile = eachFile =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (e.target.files[eachFile].size > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        return reject([{ message: `File ${e.target.files[eachFile].name} too large` }]);
      }
      const file = e.target.files[eachFile];
      let offset = 0;
      console.log(offset, 'offset', file.size, 'size');
      const defaultChunkSize = 64 * 1024; // bytes
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      const blob = file.slice(offset, offset + defaultChunkSize);
      const isEndOfFile = () => offset >= file.size;
      const testEndOfFile = () => {
        if (isEndOfFile()) {
          console.log('Done reading file');
        }
      };
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
      fileReader.onloadend = (event) => {
        const target = (event.target);
        if (target.error == null) {
          const result = target.result;
          offset += result.length;
          testEndOfFile();
          console.log(result, 'result');
          resolve(result);
        } else {
          reject(target.error);
        }
      };
    });

  return Promise.all(files.map(asyncReadFile));
}
```

Here I receive the file and I divide it. But the problem is that if the file is more than a chunk, then I should bring together him from them again and again. But how to make it in my case? I can't understand it in any way...

Please help me :) What it is necessary to make to read the file in chunks and to receive it as ArrayBuffer?

Comment: what you are doing seems very impractical. what are you trying to achieve by doing this? upload files with plain json?

Comment: why can't you just keep it as a blob/file?